# Diego enabled in bluemix but not shown in dashboard

Tags: ibm-cloud, diego

I have enabled Diego for my application in bluemix and verified in command also. But the dashboard still showing the same as DEA . I tried restarted the app and refreshed the dashboard also . Any thoughts ?

Comment: There was a problem in the UI to update the DEA flag for apps migrated to Diego, it should be working now.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the command line to [migrate an existing app to Diego](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/depapps.html#migrateapp).

After installing the [Diego-enabler CLI plugin](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/Diego-Enabler), run the command:

```
$ cf enable-diego APPLICATION_NAME
```

to migrate to Diego.

---

To verify that the app was successfully migrated, type the command:

```
$ cf has-diego-enabled APPLICATION_NAME
```

---

If you have done these two steps and the dashboard problem persists, [try restaging the application](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/start-restart-restage.html):

```
$ cf restage APPLICATION_NAME
```

This is what I did to get rid of the **DEA** symbol next to my app name.

---

On January 31, 2017, Apps are scheduled to be automatically updated to the new architecture. Let me know if you are still encountering issues after restaging your application.

Comment: Unfortunately it stopped working now after I executed the command .

Comment: Diego made some changes for the host environment variable. Verify your Bluemix app complies with those changes.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u have a check the diego property of from CLI.

```
cf curl /v2/apps/$(cf app APPLICATION_NAME --guid)
```

to check the value of diego.

when diego is true, in Dashboard UI, DEA tag should not show out.

and about app not running, maybe have a carefully reviewing to docs, as joe said about "Diego made some changes for the host environment variable"

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed this issue and it should be working now. Currently when apps are migrated from DEA to Diego through cf CLI or web UI, the UI of these apps will update automatically in both dashboard page and app details page.